# Python specify few list return types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, typing

I’m writing a python project with PyCharm. 
I have a funtion which can return multiple types:

```
list(User), list(Player), list(Builder)
```

I want to use pycharm auto complete features but it doesn’t seem to infer the right possible return types, so I read about the typing module and tried to use this syntax as return type:

```
-> Union[List[Builder], List[User], List[Player]]
```

And yet PyCharm suggest Builder’s attributes only, which is the first thing one on the Union expression. 
If I use non-list return types, typing works as expected and suggest the right attribute from all types written in the Union expression. I.E:

```
-> Union[Builder, User, Player]
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it might be, a PyCharm thing. Consider using MyPy and check if it returns an error because from mine point of view `-> Union[Builder, User, Player]` looks fine. It may also depend on your function - maybe it is not implemented properly?

Comment: If it is a Pycharm issue, maybe you should create a ticket on their side. What you mean is that, when you write code that uses this function, and want to access an attribute of this return, PyCharm, by default, proposes you attributes of the class `Builder` only. And you would like that it proposes attributes of the 3 possible classes? I am understanding correctly?

Comment: @Eskapp yes you understood correctly.

Comment: @maslak what you wrote works fine, the problem is with: -> Union[List[Builder], List[User], List[Player]]. With this expression, PyCharm suggests only Builder’s attributes

Comment: It's a bug in PyCharm, could you please file an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using for that docstrings. I kill two birds with one stone like that. The first one is having my method documented if I was not clear :)

```
def method_a():
    """
    :return:
    list of int, list of str
    """
    return [1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]
```

[image: Autocomplete with PyCharm]

Comment: Did you pay attention to the syntax `list of something` ?